# Clicking on deep link doesn't open the flutter app and navigates to page 404

Tags: flutter, deep-linking, applinks

I got a verification link in my yahoo mail clicking this link should route me to my flutter app
but it goes to page 404 and using adb test command the app is opened

I am using applinks

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var loading=true.obs;
  final _appLinks = AppLinks();
  final profileController=Get.put(ProfileController());

  @override
  void initState() {
    profileController.initData();
    Timer(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
      loading.value=false;
    });
    _appLinks.allUriLinkStream.listen((uri) {
      String? userId = uri.queryParameters['userid'];
      String? token = uri.queryParameters['token'];
      if(kDebugMode){
        print('User ID: $userId');
        print('Token: $token');
      }
      Get.offNamed("/verify_client",arguments: [userId,token]);
    });
    super.initState();
  }
}

And unilinks also 
void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await VerificationHandler.initUniLinks();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
class VerificationHandler {
  static late StreamSubscription sub;
  static  initUniLinks() async {
    final initialLink = await getInitialLink();

    sub = uriLinkStream.listen((Uri? uri) {
     if(uri!=null){
       if(kDebugMode){
         print(initialLink);
         print(uri);
       }
       if (uri.host == 'mohamyninja.com' ||uri.host=='new.mohamyninja.com'){
         String? userId = uri.queryParameters['userid'];
         String? token = uri.queryParameters['token'];
         if(kDebugMode){
           print('User ID: $userId');
           print('Token: $token');
         }
         Get.offNamed("/verify_client",arguments: [userId,token]);
       }
     }
      // Use the uri and warn the user, if it is not correct
    }, onError: (err) {
      // Handle exception by warning the user their action did not succeed
    });
  }
}
```

The manifest file configuration

```
<meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="mohamyninja.com" android:pathPrefix="/" />
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="new.mohamyninja.com" android:pathPrefix="/" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```

this is the verification link 
https://mohamyninja.com/userid=51_token=dcfde478bd46d67b5a4e1aada7b27188

Answer (score 0):

Did you create assetlinks.json and apple-app-site-association files and stored them in your server?